# Make a bootstrap Popover close when clicked outside not on the popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there anyway to stop a popover from closing when it is clicked inside? It happens when I add a `container` option.

```
$('#share_form').popover({
    'container': '#share_form',
    'html': true,
    'content': function() { return $('#popover_content').html(); },
    'title': 'My Title',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'viewport': 'body',
});

$(document).on('click', '#div_button', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Whent his is clicked, the popover closes :(");
});

<div id="popover_content" style="display:none;">
    <div id="div_button">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: This is what I ended up with that worked nicely;

```
$('#popover_button').popover({ 
    'trigger': 'manual',
    'container': '#element', /* element that moves on resize like popover_button */
    'html': true,
    'content': function() { return $('#popover_content').html(); },
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'viewport': 'body'
});

$("#popover_button").click(function(e){$('#popover_button').popover('toggle');});

$(document).click(function(e){
    //popover_element is just what was inside #popover_button
    if(e.target.id !== "popover_element" && !$(event.target).hasClass('popover-content')) 
        $("#popover_button").popover('hide');
});
```

Comment: any particular reason the default popup behaviour/syntax is not good enough for you? Like the examples at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: the default syntax closes when I click on the popover. any syntax really, i've tried it all.

Comment: Not in any of the live demos from the link (Chrome on Win7 here) - I click the button, popover shows up; I click everywhere (inside/outside the popover) and it stays there until I dismiss it by clicking on the button again...

Comment: It happens when I add a `container` to it. Which is needed if I want it to follow on window resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to tweak this a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/6zcyfrqp/1/

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover on right</button>

<div id="content" class="hidden">this is my awesome content
    <br/>includes a
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">save</button> button
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
    var options = {
        content: function () {
            return $("#content").html();
        },
        placement: "right",
        container: "body",
        toggle: "popover",
        title: 'My Title',
        html: true
    };

    $('.btn').popover(options);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. I really appreciate the time. So what's happening is. I am making my popover container the same element as the popover button itself. This is the only way I can make it actually stick as the page resizes. Because of this, when I click on it, it toggles. **EDIT**: And that was my problem. I had to attach it to something else that moves with the document in the same way. Thank you.

Comment: I see... do you want to add a more complete example of your code then? It's hard to work on a solution without knowing the full gist of the issue... do you have to use the same element as the container and the button?

Comment: Yea I know, it would just take way to long to make a fiddle for my specific issue. Sorry about that. But you helped me out a lot! Haha, sometimes you just need to work through it and ideas will pop into place. Until now I just couldn't find anything that moved with the document the same way my button did but I found something. I'd just make note that the container can't be the same as the popover trigger element. My only problem lies with making it disappear when clicked outside.

Comment: if you change the trigger to 'focus' (like in my updated sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zcyfrqp/2/) you will click on the button and it will popover.  If you click outside of it, it will hide... Is that what you need?

Comment: On Safari OSX, on your fiddle and my dev site, focus does nothing for me. No popover appears.

Comment: Hmmm, I just wrapped all the options' keys with quotes just in case.  Do you want to try it? http://jsfiddle.net/6zcyfrqp/3/ - I will try safari in a few moments (need to boot the lappy)

Comment: `tabindex="0'` fixes the the bug, however it still closes when clicking inside the popover element.

Comment: Ah! if you change it to focus, then when clicking on the popover the button does not have the focus anymore and the popover closes (so it is working as designed).  If you want more control over when/how the popover closes, I am thinking we may have to implement a manual trigger and handle the 'show' / 'hide' events ourselves...

Comment: You will need to tweak the location of where the popover is shown... but this may be closer to what you want... click on the button, popover shows... need to click on the button again to hide it -> http://jsfiddle.net/6zcyfrqp/4/

Comment: Thanks! Can you think of anyway to make it close if you click anywhere else on the screen?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to figure it out at this moment, sorry

Comment: No worries, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you may want to share it for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This is from documentation of bootstrap.

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Comment: `{"trigger": "focus"}` doesn't do anything when doing it through javascript.

Comment: Let me make sure, what you need is a button with popover witch doesn't close by clicking the button, is it correct?

And it works properly.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wataruoguchi/5eqvh0cj/1/)

Comment: You meant my code doesn't work in Safari?
It works in Safari, version 8.0.3.

Comment: My apologies. `tabindex` fixes the safari bug. However, When you click on content in the popover, it closes. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. My problem is when I click on things inside the popover, it closes.